# Place Item to Bottom React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm creating a react native app i have a item - a plus button(shown in image)
[image: button]

I want this to the bottom of my page onto footer - [image]

but the problem is that when i place this button on bottom with `position: 'absolute', bottom: 0` it's only going to the bottom of the hero section & not to the footer

Code -

```
<View style={styles.main}>
<View style={styles.hero}>
  <View style={styles.flex}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
     
    </View>
  </View>
  <View style={styles.flex2}>

      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>

    <View style={styles.container12}>
      
    </View>
  </View>
</View>


<TouchableOpacity>
  <View style={styles.container33}>
    <EntypoIcon name="plus" style={styles.icon28}></EntypoIcon>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Main Styles -

```
  main: {
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',
},
hero: {
  alignSelf: 'stretch',
  height: 250,
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
  borderBottomLeftRadius: 50,
  borderBottomRightRadius: 50,
},
  container33: {
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  backgroundColor: '#1DA6FA',
  // flex: 1,
  borderRadius: 50,
  position: 'absolute',
  bottom: 0,
  right: 10,
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center'
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem si that you are applying the `absolute` css position to the `View` inside the `TouchableOpacity` and not to the `TouchableOpacity` itself.

To achieve what you want to do, you should write something like:

```
<View style={styles.absoluteOpacity}>
   <TouchableOpacity>
     <View style={styles.container33}>
       <EntypoIcon name="plus" style={styles.icon28}></EntypoIcon>
     </View>
   </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

And then the css:

```
container33: {
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  backgroundColor: '#1DA6FA',
  // flex: 1,
  borderRadius: 50,
  right: 10,
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center'
},
absoluteOpacity: {
   position: 'absolute',
   bottom: 0,
}
```